# Display specific record when link in email is clicked

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

how do I include a link in an email that when clicked it would display data for one record only?

Right now I have a datatable in the index page that displays all records when the app opens up. When a change to a record is made an email is sent out with the id number of the record that was edited.

I am supposing I have to create another view just for this? I was thinking I need to implement a GET action in a controller that accepts id as a parameter, searches the underlying data store and returns appropriate record.

Also, I found this   [Open Specified ASP.NET MVC Views From Hyperlinks Inside Email Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929947/open-specified-asp-net-mvc-views-from-hyperlinks-inside-email-body)   but I cannot quite understand what is going on as there is login stuff and other things involved as well.

How do I go about this as I have never done it before? Could you please provide some example code? Thanks a lot.

This is the code i have so far which works but it is missing the piece i am asking for:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditOneRecord(Ticket tix, string action, string confirm_value)
{
    if (action == "Save")
    {
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
                //Send email to user if IT edits the record     
                if (userName != tix.vcAssignedTo)
                { 
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();      
                    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("nsantagata@fieldaero.com");
                    mailMessage.To.Add("nsantagata@fieldaero.com");
                    mailMessage.Subject = "Your Ticket Has Been Edited";
                    mailMessage.Body = "Your ticket " + tix.iNumber + " has been updated";
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                }

            db.Entry(tix).State = EntityState.Modified;
            tix.dtLastUpdated = System.DateTime.Now;       

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    //Save to knowledgebase
    if (confirm_value == "Yes")
    {
        HelpDeskDBHandle HDdb = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
        if (HDdb.AddKnowledgeBase(tix))
        {
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: `I was thinking I need to implement a GET action in a controller that accepts id as a parameter, searches the underlying data store and returns appropriate record.` yes that's what you need to do. ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional param.
if he has a value then you sort by it, else  you will return the page as is.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index?id=1212");
```

some thing like this.

Comment: I would please need some example code.  What I have is the index page which shows all records.  Then I can click on the edit button of a record on this page and it goes to a tab that populates with the data from the record to edit.  After hitting save, the changes are saved to the database and the email is sent.